# Given a positive integer $m$, show that if there exists a prime $p$ such $p\equiv 1\pmod m$ then there exist infinitely many.

Tags: number-theory

This is part of a problem from Niven and Zuckerman's Introduction to Number Theory, 5th ed.  From section 2.8, excerise 36 (a).  The problem references an article in The American Mathematical Monthly which states that if there is a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 1\pmod m$, then there exists a prime $p_2$ such that $p_2\equiv 1\bmod mp$.  I've tried using the fact that any positive integers $a$ and $k$ with $a\ge 2$ we have $n\mid\phi(a^k-1)$, from exercise 33, but no luck.  Any hints?

Comment: Replace $m$ with $mp$ and apply the result again.

Comment: Do you want to prove the question in your title, or the referenced article from the AMM?

Comment: The question in my original title.

Comment: [Theorem 47](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf). Proof provided involves cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: KCd  so I should assume that all integers have at least one prime is congruent to 1 modulo the particular integer?

Comment: Sathvik Acharya, thanks but this is not exactly what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: Thomas Andrews, you changed my title. But the new statement is not what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: KCd you've cleared this up for me thanks.  I knew it was something very simple.

Comment: So, presumably, the question wants you to use the magazine theorem to solve the title question?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski  you need to put @ in front of a username for the user to be notified of your message to them here. I had originally changed your title and Thomas Andrews then quickly fixed a LaTeX error I made. Now I see you have reverted your title back to its original mistaken form.  You are *not* being asked "for a given $m$" to do anything.  You are supposed to assume for *every* $m$ that there is a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod m$ and then prove for *every* $m$ that there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod m$.  There is *no reasonable way* that "for a given $m$" you can do anything.

Comment: The hint I gave in my first comment is useless "for a given $m$".  Just think about it for $m = 5$.  Merely knowing there is a single prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$, there is no reasonable way to deduce that there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$. Only by assuming something for *every* $m$ can you make progress. In particular, the hint in my first comment is useless if you only know the desired conclusion "for a given $m$" since then there's no way you can replace $m$ with $mp$: that would be a new $m$. You need to pay more careful attention to the way quantifiers are being used.

Comment: That is why your title reflects a misunderstanding you have, at least about how to *express* what you're trying to do even if it is not what you were literally trying to do.

Comment: @KCd Thanks for your comments.  I did realize my mistake after your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what the question is asking - I'd guess the question wants you to prove the title using the given theorem from American Mathematical Monthly.

However, the usual way to prove your title question, without using the full [Dirichlet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), is to use the [cyclotomic polynomial,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_m(x).$

Essentially, these polynomials are designed to have, as roots, the primitive $m$th roots of unity.

So if $n$ is an integer, and $p\mid \Phi_m(n)$ then $n^m\equiv 1\pmod p$ but $n^k\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ for $k<m.$ This means $m$ is the order of $n$ modulo $p,$ so $m\mid (p-1).$ (But this isn't 100% true, so you have to take care - there are a finite number of cases where it isn't true. The other prime divisors occur when $x^m-1$ has a double root, modulo $p,$ which only happens when $p\mid m.$)

Then you do something like Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes, and instead apply it to:

$$\Phi_m(mp_1p_2\cdots p_n),$$ where $m$ is added to remove the finite exceptions, and show that it has a prime factor $p\equiv 1\pmod m$ and $p\neq p_i$ for any $i.$

---

For example, when $m=4,$ $\Phi_4(n)=n^2+1,$ and we know any prime dividing $n^2+1$ is either $2$ or a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$

So given a finite set of primes $p_1,\dots,p_n\equiv 1\pmod 4,$ consider a prime factor $p$ of $$(2p_1\cdots p_n)^2+1$$ It cannot be $2$ or any $p_k,$ so  we have an additional $p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$

---

When $m=6,$ $\Phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1.$  So any prime divisor $p$ of $\Phi_6(6n)=36n^2-6n+1$ satisfies $\equiv 1\pmod 6.$

You can actually use $f(n)=\Phi_6(3n)=9n^2-3n+1,$ because $\Phi_6(n)$ is never even.

Turns out $f(1)=7,f(2)=31,f(3)=73,...,f(7)=421$ are all primes, but $f(8)=553=7\cdot 79.$

[Of course, it was inevitable that $f(8)\equiv f(1)\equiv 0\pmod{7}.$ You will also have $f(33)\equiv f(2)\equiv 0\pmod {31}.$]

---

The usual version of Euclid's proof uses $\Phi_2(x)=x+1.$ But it just as well could have used $\Phi_1(x)=x-1.$

Comment: Why is $\Phi_m(mp_1p_2\cdots p_n)$ prime?

Comment: It isn't, it is divisible by s ptimr. @KentaS From what I wrote: "... and show that it has a prime factor"

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread it.

Comment: It is possible, if you don't know the ins and outs of the polynomials, that $\Phi_m(mp_1\cdots p_n)=\pm 1,$ and thus does not have a prime factor. That requires more knowledge about the polynomials, but, without knowing more, you can show that not all $\Phi_m(kmp_1\dots p_n)$ are $\pm 1,$ $k=1,2,\dots$ because the $\Phi_m$ is a non-constant polynomial, and thus cannot take the same value for infinitely often. @KentaS